# Access Spring Cloud Stream Kafka materialized view with external client

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, materialized-views

Let's pretend that my Java application using *Spring Cloud Streams Kafka* creates a materialized view (KTable) that will be used to fulfil **get(id)** request.

How can I see the data from "outside" if I would like to do some maintenance or troubleshooting? Is there a way to explore/reprocess collected data as connecting directly to materialized view (like assigning to a topic) from another external application and convert it to stream? One option is creating specialized REST API that will map request to materialized view methods. Is there a better more efficient way? Does Spring Cloud Streams provides such? May be a tool?

Comment: Spring Cloud Stream binder for Kafka Streams does not provide this feature today. The REST layer must reside in the same Kafkfa Streams processor to access it through an HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Here is an open issue that is kind of related to what you are asking: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2424

Comment: Feel free to comment on that issue and make a feature request. Then we can explore some potential solutions.

Comment: I'll get it. Thank you @sobychacko!